# SAS Web App Server SASServer6_1 is still in the process of starting up, proceeding with additional servers

Tags: spring, sas, gemfire

After installing HotFix using SASHFADD, the SAS CIS web interface does not open.

In the SASCustIntelCore6.6.log I see the following error:

> **WARN** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sas.svcs.cache.cacheableBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [com/sas/svcs/data/caches/gemfire/sas_gemfire_config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sas_gemfire_cache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service. Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist. Configured list of locators is "[test-mid(null):41415]".
> **ERROR** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sas.svcs.cache.cacheableBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [com/sas/svcs/data/caches/gemfire/sas_gemfire_config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sas_gemfire_cache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service. Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist. Configured list of locators is "[test-mid(null):41415]". at
> at com.sas.svcs.webapp.servlet.springframework.DefaultContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(DefaultContextLoaderListener.java:44) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service. Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist. Configured list of locators is "[stl-test-mid(null):41415]". at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:173)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ...
> 28 more Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service. Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist. Configured list of locators is "[test-mid(null):41415]". at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TCPGOSSIP.sendGetMembersRequest(TCPGOSSIP.java:222) at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.PingSender.run(PingSender.java:85) ... 1 more
> **DEBUG** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] .crm.spring.client.SASEnvironmentFactory - Unable to lookup ServiceRegistry in serviceURL DAO.
> **DEBUG** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] .crm.spring.client.SASEnvironmentFactory - Using service registry defaultValue

In gemfire.log:

> [**warning** tid=0x16] org/springframework/util/StringUtils java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StringUtils at org.springframework.shell.core.Completion.(Completion.java:50) at org.springframework.shell.core.Completion.(Completion.java:35) at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.converters.LogLevelConverter.(LogLevelConverter.java:34) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)

When installing hotfixes, the instructions from the documentation for the hotfixes were followed, and post-installation work was also completed. The security service has been updated to version 12

What could be the reason?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDt1F.png)

I'm having trouble generating a date in a query from SAS CIS in an Oracle database. The fix I need is https://support.sas.com/kb/66/498.html
I separately downloaded the patch package, which includes hotfix 66498, and followed the hotfix deployment procedure from start to finish.